# Can't Add Parameter To Query String

Tags: c#, ms-access, oledb, ms-access-2013

I need to have a second copy of a MS Access table that will be saved in a network drive. And since splitting is not an option because it drastically slows the application down, I decided to just manually "merge" the data after a certain user action like clicking an **exit** button.

I have this query string

```
public const string MERGETOMAIN = @"INSERT INTO tbl_name (UserID, ...)" + 
     " IN 'C:\Users\nathan\Desktop\copy.accdb' SELECT TOP 1 UserId, ... " +
     " FROM tbl_name WHERE UserID = @currentUser ORDER BY ROWID DESC";
```

...and it works when I do this:

```
using (OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand(Helpers.Queries.MERGETOMAIN, mergeConn))
                {
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@currentUser", currentUserID);
                    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                }
```

But, as you notice, the path to the copy is hardcoded. I wanted it to be dynamic so I tried using a parameter like I always do, so I replaced it with a question mark:

```
public const string MERGETOMAIN = @"INSERT INTO tbl_name (UserID, ...)" + 
     " IN ? SELECT TOP 1 UserId, ... " +
     " FROM tbl_name WHERE UserID = @currentUser ORDER BY ROWID DESC";
```

But this results in the following error:

> Your network access was interrupted. To continue close the database and then open it again.

So instead of a question mark, I used **@parameterName**. But, when I do, I get the following error:

> The file "foo\foo\@parameterName" cannot be found.

The weird thing is, the other paremeter, **@currentUser**, is working just fine.

I'm not really sure what is happening here, but the only thing that works right now is to hardcode the path. I tried looking through similar questions but no dice.

Any idea will be greatly appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: Why not just store it in the Config file or something and just concatenate it into your query string?

Comment: As a matter of fact, I do have the path stored in the config file and I am using that to supply the value to the parameter. I guess I just got used to the idea that concatinating values to query strings is bad. But thank you. I'll give it a try.

Comment: Some say that writing SQL in code is bad. Do what works and if you have time to implement something else, try it out.

Answer (score 0):

You can write a method which creates the string for you.

```
public string getMergeToMain(string path)
        {
            string strRet;

            if (path != null)
            {
                strRet = @"INSERT INTO FSO_LogSheet (UserID, ...)" +
                     " IN '" + path + "' SELECT TOP 1 UserId, ... " +
                     " FROM FSO_LogSheet WHERE UserID = @currentUser ORDER BY ROWID DESC";
                return strRet;
            }
            else
            {    //Error, not agood habit to return null...
                return null;
            }
        }
```

With the method parameter "path", you can set the path dynamically.

You can call it for example by

```
OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand(fooClass.getMergeToMain(@"C:\users\bar.accdb"), mergeConn)
```

I assume that you know the difference between public, private and static methods, so please do not forget to set it right for your own needs.